# how to print out multiple lines from mysql in fpdf

Tags: php, mysqli, printing, fpdf

Can anyone assist me with this please?

I am trying to print out multiple ingredients from the table ingredeients
unto the fpdf so i can save it as a pdf, but for some reason when i output
the column, it only prints the last item. 
 here is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL | E_STRICT');
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
// Start the session
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid']) && empty($_SESSION['userid'])) {
  header( 'Location: indexwlogin.php' ) ;
}
?>
<?php
$listitems = $_REQUEST['id'];
//MySQL Database Connect 
//select ingredients.ingredient from grocery inner join ingredients on grocery.ingredients_id = ingredients.id where ingredients.recipeing_id ='1'
include 'dbconnect.php';
$sqlstatement4 = "select grocery.id, recipes.name from grocery inner join ingredients on grocery.ingredients_id = ingredients.id inner join recipes on ingredients.recipeingd_id = recipes.id where grocery.user_id ='".$_SESSION['userid']."'";
    $sql_result4 = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlstatement4) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result4)) 
     { 
         $groceryid = $row["id"];
         $ingname = $row["name"];
     }

$sqlstatement3 = "select ingredients.ingredient from grocery inner join ingredients on grocery.ingredients_id = ingredients.id where ingredients.recipeingd_id ='".$listitems."'";
    $sql_result3 = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlstatement3) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result3)) 
     { 
         $ings = $row["ingredient"];

     }


require("fpdf17/fpdf.php");

$grocerylist = new FPDF();
$grocerylist->AddPage();
$grocerylist->SetFont("Arial","B","20");
$grocerylist->Cell(0,10,"Grocery List for $ingname",1,1,"C");

$grocerylist->SetFont("Arial","I","20");
$grocerylist->Cell(50,40,"$ings",1,1,"C");
 //$grocerylist->Cell(50,40, $ings,1,1,'C');
$grocerylist->Output();

?>
```

Comment: You are storing value of single array only in the while loops that you are executing, instead make those vairable to array variable to array variables in the while loops

Answer (score 0):

`while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result3)){
$grocerylist->Cell(50,40,$row['ingredient']);
$grocerylist->Ln();
}`

Hi, use this way use either foreach or while.And if this also didn't work 
`var_dump($sql_result3)` to check how many and which records you are getting.